# Discrete faithful representation in $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ and horocycles in hyperbolic space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $S$ be a closed oriented surface of genus $g>1$. Is the following true ?

> Let $\alpha,\beta\in \pi_1(S)\backslash \{1\}$ and $\rho:\pi_1(S)\rightarrow PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ be a discrete faithful representation. Assume that there exists a horocycle $h$ in $\mathbb H^2$ such that the horocycles $h, \rho(\alpha)(h)$ and $\rho(\beta)(h)$ have the same based point. Then $\alpha=\beta$.

Here, the based point of a horocycle $h$ in $\mathbb H$ is the unique tangent point of $h$ to the boundary of $\mathbb H$.

Comment: What is "based point" of a horocycle?

Comment: @studiosus I believe Bebop is referring to the unique point of the horocycle on the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @guest: I think so too, but it should be Bebop's responsibility to write a clear question. Incidentally, the  answer to the question in your formulation is negative.

Comment: You are right, by "based point" I meant the unique tangent point of the horocycle to the boundary of $\mathbb H$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you are asking that $h$ and $\rho(a)h$ have the same base point, but this means $\rho(a)$ will fix that point on the boundary.  Then the entire orbit $\rho(a^n)$ will fix the point, so any $b=a^n$ will satisfy your condition with $b\neq a$.